# Elasticsearch: Facet script and facet_filter

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

Is it possible to use facet script and facet filter in elasticsearch like this?

```
{
  "facets": {
    "judges": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "judges.untouched",
        "size": 10,
        "all_terms": false,
        "script": { "script": "...", "params": { }}
      },
      "global_facets": false,
      "facet_filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "query": "..... ",
                "fields": [
                  "judges.analyzed"
                ],
                "default_operator": "and",
                "analyze_wildcard": true
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Because when i run this query, elasticsearch raises error: Parse Failure [No facet type found for [and]]]; }.

Thanks

Comment: I gave this a try and couldn't reproduce your error. Can you provide a [curl recreation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/help/)?

Comment: I modified facet_filter to use { query: { filtered: { and: {..}}} and the query parses.

Comment: Then you are using a query filter, which contains a filtered query, which contains a filter. This doesn't make much sense. I suspect there was something else that was going wrong with your query. And I doubt that the json provided in the answer that you accepted actually works.

Comment: sorry, i forget to add filter to filtered. This works { query: { filtered: { filter: { and: {..}}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** Incorrect answer. I'm leaving it because of context. 
To clarify: `and`  is an appropriate filter and should be accepted by `facet_filter`. Not sure what's up.

Untested, but from the docs: (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/)

> All facets can be configured with an additional filter (explained in the Query DSL section)

So you need to put an appropriate `query` in `facet_filter`. `And` is NOT an appropriate filter (the error you receive could be clearer)

e.g:

```
"facet_filter" : {
   "term" : { "user" : "kimchy"}
}
```

You'd probably want something like:

```
"facet_filter" : {
   "query_string": {
      "query": "..... ",
      "fields": [
         "judges.analyzed"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the case. The `facet_filter` has to contain a filter, whereas `and` is a valid type of filter. In your example you put a query (query_string) instead of a filter there, which is wrong.

Comment: @Javanna: yeah you're right. Hmm. I'll edit the answer to indicate it's incorrect. Not sure what's invalid with the original question btw. Seems correct to me.

Comment: Thanks! I tested that query and it worked for me, I guess there must be something missing here.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an `and` filter is:

```
"facet_filter": {
  "and": {
    "filters": [
       {
         // filter definition
       },
       {
         // another filter definition
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

But you're using only a single condition, so there's no need of an `and` filter.
You should just have:

```
   "facet_filter": {
     "query": {
       "query_string": {
         "query": "..."
       }
     }
   }
```